# array_flip to print duplicate values in comma separated format

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use `array_flip` to print duplicate values in a comma separated format

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"blue");
$flip=array_flip($a);
print_r($flip);
```

My output is:

```
Array ( [red] => a [green] => b [blue] => d )
```

But my intended output is:

```
Array ( [red] => a [green] => b [blue] => c,d)
```

How can I get that output?

Comment: array_flip doesn't work that way. You'll have to implement your own function.

Comment: Hi there! I edited your post to make some of the formatting clearer. The quote format (made with `>`) is usually reserved for sentences or paragraphs of English, not code. Output and error codes can be formatted like programming code. I also removed the bolding, you should use that sparingly. And I rewrote it with english sentences. Your post looked like a brief for an exercise and was harder to read. Making it easier for other users to read leads to better answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your function along with `array_flip` like as

```
$array = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"blue");

$res = array_flip($array);

foreach ($res as $k => $v)
    $res[$k] = implode(", ", array_keys($array, $k));
print_r($res);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [red] => a
    [green] => b
    [blue] => c, d
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/442238)

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

`array_flip` will not give your expected output. Instead of this you can write your custom function like:

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"blue");
$flip = array_flip_custom($a);

print_r($flip);
function array_flip_custom($a){
    $flip = array();
    foreach($a as $index=>$key){
        if($flip[$key]){
            $flip[$key] .= ','.$index;
        } else {
            $flip[$key] = $index;
        }
    }
    return $flip;
}
```

Will give output:

> Array ( [red] => a [green] => b [blue] => c,d )